# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer & Other Errno messages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that generates a CSV by calling an API lots of times that has successfully run in the past, however now I am getting Errno messages. Most commonly [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer, [Errno 60] Operation timed out, and sometimes [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

This specific script calls an API around 16-24k times (I am 100% sure this is below the ratelimit) and when it ran successfully took around 2-3 hours to complete. For some reason, I can't seem to get it to run successfully without getting an error of some sort a while into the script running. So it will call an API route hundreds/thousands of time and then out of nowhere spit out one of the errors for calling the same exact one it's already been calling successfully. It seems strange. I've provided the error messages below as well.

I've removed some sensitive information such as the token and API routes as this is private data! I've left the errors in tact though.

```
import http.client
import json
import csv



class mgrData:


    def __init__(self):

        self.token = '[REMOVED]'
        self.userDict = {}


    def getPeakData(self, route):

        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("[REMOVED]")
        bod = ''
        headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ str(self.token),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        conn.request("GET", route, bod, headers)

        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()

        return json.loads(data)




    def PeakExport(self):

        print("Please wait, data generating...")
        raw = self.getPeakData("[REMOVED]")
        totalrecords = raw['meta']['page']['total']
        resultspp = len(raw['data'])


        if totalrecords % resultspp == 0:
            numpages = int(totalrecords/resultspp)
        elif totalrecords % resultspp != 0:
            numpages = int(totalrecords//resultspp + 1)

        mainDct = {}
        for i in range(1,numpages+1):
            route = "[REMOVED]"
            dct = self.getPeakData(route)
            data = dct['data']


            for i in data:


                pkEmpID = i['attributes']['identifier'].split('_')[0]
                name = i['attributes']['name']

               # segID = i['id']

                hrisIDget = self.getPeakData("[REMOVED]")

                hrisID = hrisIDget['urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User']['employeeNumber']

                if pkEmpID in mainDct:
                    if i['attributes']['direct'] == True:
                        dSegID = i['id']
                        mainDct[pkEmpID].append({'dSegID' : dSegID})


                    if i['attributes']['direct'] == False:
                        aSegID = i['id']
                        mainDct[pkEmpID].append({'aSegID' : aSegID})


                else:
                    mainDct.update({pkEmpID : []})
                    mainDct[pkEmpID].append({'name': name})
                    mainDct[pkEmpID].append({'EID' : hrisID})

                    if i['attributes']['direct'] == True:
                        dSegID = i['id']
                        mainDct[pkEmpID].append({'dSegID' : dSegID})


                    if i['attributes']['direct'] == False:
                        aSegID = i['id']
                        mainDct[pkEmpID].append({'aSegID' : aSegID})




        urllist = []
        for key in mainDct:
            switch = False
            for i in mainDct[key]:

                if 'aSegID' in i:
                    switch = True

                    data = self.getPeakData("[REMOVED]" % (i['aSegID']))

                    if 'mean' in data['data']['attributes']['scores']:
                        score = data['data']['attributes']['scores']['mean']
                        participation = data['data']['attributes']['participation']['mean']
                        nps = data['data']['attributes']['scores']['nps']['score']

                        mainDct[key].append({'engagement all': score})
                        mainDct[key].append({'nps all': nps})
                        mainDct[key].append({'participation all' : participation})

                    elif 'anonymity' in data['data']['attributes']['scores']:
                        mainDct[key].append({'engagement all':'Anonymity'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'nps all': 'Anonymity'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'participation all': 'Anonymity'})


                    else:
                        mainDct[key].append({'engagement all': 'N/A'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'nps all':'N/A'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'participation all': 'N/A'})

            if switch == False:
                mainDct[key].append({'aSegID' : 'None'})
                mainDct[key].append({'engagement all' :'N/A'})
                mainDct[key].append({'nps all': 'N/A'})
                mainDct[key].append({'participation all: N/A'})

        for key in mainDct:
            switch = False
            for i in mainDct[key]:
                if 'dSegID' in i:
                    switch = True

                    data = self.getPeakData("[REMOVED]" % (i['dSegID']))

                    if 'mean' in data['data']['attributes']['scores']:
                        score = data['data']['attributes']['scores']['mean']
                        participation = data['data']['attributes']['participation']['mean']
                        nps = data['data']['attributes']['scores']['nps']['score']


                        mainDct[key].append({'engagement direct': score})
                        mainDct[key].append({'nps direct': nps})
                        mainDct[key].append({'participation direct': participation})

                    elif 'anonymity' in data['data']['attributes']['scores']:
                        mainDct[key].append({'engagement direct': 'Anonymity'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'nps direct': 'Anonymity'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'participation direct': 'Anonymity'})

                    else:
                        mainDct[key].append({'engagement direct': 'N/A'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'nps direct': 'N/A'})
                        mainDct[key].append({'participation direct': 'N/A'}) 

            if switch == False:
                mainDct[key].append({'dSegID' : 'None'}) 
                mainDct[key].append({'engagement direct': 'N/A'})
                mainDct[key].append({'nps direct': 'N/A'})
                mainDct[key].append({'participation direct': 'N/A'})                                    




        with open('Output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            csvwriter.writerow(['Manager ID', 'Manager Name','Direct Engagement', 'All Engagement', 'Direct NPS', 'All NPS', 'Direct Participation', 'All Participation'])
            for key in mainDct:
                for i in mainDct[key]:
                    if 'name' in i:
                        name = i['name']
                    if 'EID' in i:
                        EID = i['EID']
                    if 'nps direct' in i:
                        ND = i['nps direct']
                    if 'engagement direct' in i:
                        ED = i['engagement direct']
                    if 'participation direct' in i:
                        PD = i['participation direct']
                    if 'engagement all' in i:
                        EA = i['engagement all']
                    if 'nps all' in i:
                        NA = i['nps all']
                    if 'participation all' in i:
                        PA = i['participation all']

                csvwriter.writerow([EID,name,ED,EA,ND,NA,PD,PA])


def main():
    thisSync = mgrData()
    thisSync.PeakExport()




main()
```

Some errors I receive:

```
Please wait, data generating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 209, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 204, in main
    thisSync.PeakExport()
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 72, in PeakExport
    hrisIDget = self.getPeakData("/scim/v2/users/employee_"+str(pkEmpID))
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 31, in getPeakData
    res = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
[Finished in 1263.8s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3', '-u', '/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py']]
[dir: /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

```
Please wait, data generating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 209, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 204, in main
    thisSync.PeakExport()
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 72, in PeakExport
    hrisIDget = self.getPeakData("/scim/v2/users/employee_"+str(pkEmpID))
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/BI Scripts/Random.py", line 31, in getPeakData
    res = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: Can you handle the TimeoutError and ConnectionResetError in your code? And setup some retry limit. This will probably work for you

Comment: Thanks @BruceShen, I think that's got to be it. The issue appears to be with my network.